# power analysis: power.t.test and power.anova.test result different?

Tags: r, statistical-power

When the number of groups is 2, the result of `power.t.test` and `power.anova.test` should be the same. However, the following code does not give an identical result.

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(100)
groups = rep(c("A","B"),each = 50)
power.t.test(n = 10, delta = mean(x[groups=="A"]) - mean(x[groups=='B']), sd = sqrt(anova(lm(x~groups))["Residuals", "Mean Sq"]))
power.anova.test(groups = 2,n=10, within.var = anova(lm(x~groups))["Residuals", "Mean Sq"], between.var = anova(lm(x~groups))["group", "Mean Sq"])
```

I think the `sd` in the t-test power is the square root of `within.var` in the ANOVA power, which is the within-group variance, whereas the `between.var` is the between-group variance. I got the within- and between- from the `anova(lm(x~groups))` respectively. The `delta` in the t-test power is the estimated true mean different.

The results are not the same. The `power.t.test` gives a power of `0.02740886`, while the `power.anova.test` gives `0.05904108`.

I don't know where is incorrect here.

Comment: Why are you computing power at an observed difference?

Comment: @Glen_b Hi, I am just trying to understand the difference between `power.t.test` and `power.anova.test`. The delta and between.var are all observed from the same data. I thought they should give the same result...